# Python script failing to run on Mac

Tags: python, macos, yolo

I have a Python script on my system with simple code named main.py; however, executing this file throws a lot of errors that I do not understand.

The code in main.py is as follows:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
#Load Model
model = YOLO("yolo8n.yaml") #Build New Model

#Use model
results = model.train(data="config.yaml", epochs=2) #train the model
```

Errors are in the image attached:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ultralytics import YOLO
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ultralytics/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ultralytics.models import RTDETR, SAM, YOLO
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ultralytics/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .rtdetr import RTDETR
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ultralytics/models/rtdetr/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .model import RTDETR
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ultralytics/models/rtdetr/model.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ultralytics.engine.model import Model
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ultralytics/engine/model.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ultralytics.cfg import TASK2DATA, get_cfg, get_save_dir
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ultralytics/cfg/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ultralytics.utils import (ASSETS, DEFAULT_CFG, DEFAULT_CFG_DICT, DEFAULT_CFG_PATH, LOGGER, RANK, ROOT, RUNS_DIR,
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ultralytics/utils/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/python-3.8/cv2.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: @rpath/libtiff.5.dylib
  Referenced from: <80BA7539-042B-39DF-A17F-478DE81ACD44> /opt/miniconda3/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.4.6.0.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_f6tvh9615u/croot/opencv-suite_1691620375715/work/build/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_f6tvh9615u/croot/opencv-suite_1691620375715/work/build/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/miniconda3/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_f6tvh9615u/croot/opencv-suite_1691620375715/work/build/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_f6tvh9615u/croot/opencv-suite_1691620375715/work/build/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/miniconda3/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_f6tvh9615u/croot/opencv-suite_1691620375715/work/build/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_f6tvh9615u/croot/opencv-suite_1691620375715/work/build/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/python-3.8/../../../../libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_f6tvh9615u/croot/opencv-suite_1691620375715/work/build/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_f6tvh9615u/croot/opencv-suite_1691620375715/work/build/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/python-3.8/../../../../libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/miniconda3/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/miniconda3/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/miniconda3/bin/../lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/miniconda3/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/miniconda3/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/miniconda3/bin/../lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

[image]

I tried removing Python and installing it again with no luck.

I have never seen anything like this before,

Comment: It would help if you posted your code and errors (*as text*).

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Looks like you're missing libtiff... I think.

Comment: The error looks like an installation problem with a Conda library. How is your Conda environment set up, how did you install this specific library, what do you get when you google the error message? See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: I have attached the code and the error thrown as text.
@ewokx

Comment: @tripleee I am not sure, as I did not install it recently. Would removing it and reinstalling help?

Comment: Without the requested details, all we can tell you is what's already in the error message. It's meaningless to speculate about what might or might not work when the question doesn't contain enough information to understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looking for the tiff library that is supposed to be in `/opt/miniconda3/lib/libtiff.5.dylib`.  That miniconda3 installation (of cv2 in particular) needs to be replaced in order for your particular cv2 analysis to run.

Comment: I did remove miniconda3 and added it again, and the file `/opt/miniconda3/lib/libtiff.5.dylib` was now available. Thanks